# Computer boots into 'grub rescue' mode, after not having found the 'grub_xputs' symbol

Tags: boot, upgrade, grub2

After having made an upgrade and rebooted as requested, my computer fails to start properly. It indicates: "error: the symbol 'grub_xputs' not found", and underneath I have a "grub rescue" prompt.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to purge and reinstall Grub 2 from the Live CD.

All instructions are given extremely well on this page: [HOWTO: Purge and Reinstall Grub 2 from the Live CD](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099).